# PowerShell script to select some files in a directory

Tags: powershell

Right now I have a script that will get the last five files in a directory. It looks like this:

```
$diffs = Get-ChildItem "C:\usr\local\work\tnl\Database\ReleaseScripts" -Filter "*.sql" | Sort-Object Name -Descending | Select-Object -first 5 | Sort-Object Name
```

I need to have it select all of the last files starting with a certain one. For example, if the files were named

201.txt 
202.txt 
 
203.txt 
204.txt 
 
up to  
210.txt

I might need to select all the files starting with 203.txt to the end of the list.

I could get the file name of the one I'm looking for and use that in the script. I'm just not familiar with what scripting tools I have to do that. Is there a way to edit my line to get it to do that in just one line, or will I have to put it in a loop to get my results?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is works but needs to be expanded if you file name structure is any more complex or there is a chance your original filter would grab non conforming file names.

```
$diffs = Get-ChildItem "C:\usr\local\work\tnl\Database\ReleaseScripts" -Filter "*.sql" |?
{[Int][System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex]::match($_.name,"\d+").Value -gt 201 }| 
Sort-Object Name -Descending | Select-Object -first 5 | Sort-Object Name
```

Comment: +1 - Good point on lexical vs. numerical comparison. I was assuming this was fine based on his original script which sorts alphabetically by name.

Comment: Thanks I got that to work for me, I also tried 
`$diffs = Get-ChildItem "C:\usr\local\work\tnl\Database\ReleaseScripts" -Filter "*.sql" | Sort-Object Name -Descending | Where-Object {$_.name -gt "201"}  | Sort-Object Name`
using the Where-Object instead of select-object. I was worried this wouldn't actually select the objects but it seemed to do what I wanted

Comment: Just note that sql 2001 will fail the greater then test since it is lexical less

Comment: This won't work once you have numbers with different digit counts, eg if you have numbers 1 to 10 it will sort them as: `9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 10  1`